# Make bevel modifier segments the same size

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I am trying to recreate this bevel effect without the wierd triangles probably some import thing

[image: Low Poly bevel]

But when I add a bevel modifier, and select 2 segments, The segments are not the same size.

[image]

Is there a way I can make the segments the same size?

Comment: I’m guessing you selected Percent as the Width type. Try something else. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/bevel.html

Comment: have you applied the scale in Object mode?